# How do create the transaction for particular connection only in sql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a transaction in sql for a particular connection only. It should lock down that table for all connections but allow other connections to read that table even if the transaction has began from another connection. What Isolation Level should i use for it.

```
Tran = CnnTran.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the select query you can either use use `WITH (NOLOCK)` or `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`.

READ UNCOMMITTED: Specifies that statements can read rows that have been modified by other transactions but not yet committed. Therefore, select statements can read the rows that were updated by other uncommitted transactions. So, the isolation level needs to be set on the other connection that you want to read that table.

If you want you can set this at the connection:

```
var myConnection = new SqlConnection();

// connection for reading uncommitted transactions
myConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted).Commit();
```

Or you could just do it inside a transaction if you wish:

```
using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    myConnection.Open();
    using (var transaction = myConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)) {
        // do stuff
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, How can i implement it on C# code?

Comment: I have added some code there. Also, in the SQL you are executing you could use the WITH (NOLOCK) hint - that does the same as IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted

Comment: Thanks for the example let me try this.

Comment: It works great...thanks buddy, You just saved my life otherwise i have to spent 3-4 days to manage it.

Comment: @Shell No problem, glad to be of help.