# How to determine if a transaction has already started in SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, transactions, sqltransaction

I am using a `SqlTransaction` in my code. In my previous post I was having issue when one connection is having transaction lock with `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommited` then how do I create another connection without lock. ([How do create the transaction for particular connection only in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25621297/3761928)). Now, I got my answer and *Donal* has suggested me to use `myConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted).Commit();`

Now, I am getting issue in above line sometimes.

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

I don't know what would be the issue here. This issue comes only when another thread is running. I am also using same connection in different thread.

The above error also happens whenever I try to execute any query or trying to fill `DataTable` using `DataAdapter`.

I can't figure it out what could be the issue here?